# Multiple items insert into MySQL Tables using PHP Error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert multiple items to MySQL tables using PHP in Codigniter by considering qty or serial number. I used the following controller to do that.

```
    public function addInventoryPurchase()
    {
        $this->checkPermissions('add', 'inventorystockUpdate');
        $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Update Inventory Stock'));
        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Update Inventory Stock', 'bc' => $bc);
        $this->data['supplier'] = $this->Item_model->getSupplier();
        $this->data['products'] = $this->Item_model->getInventoryProducts();
        $this->data['item_categories'] = $this->Item_model->getItemCategories();
        $this->data['auto_grn_no'] = $this->Item_model->generate_inv_grn_ref();
    
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('supplier', 'Supplier', 'required');
    
        $str = $this->input->post('auto_grn_no');
        $auto_grn = preg_replace("/[^0-9]{1,4}/", '', $str);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $stock = array(
                'office_id' => $this->session->userdata('office_id'),
                'supplier' => $this->input->post('supplier'),
                'ro_no' => $this->input->post('ro_no'),         
                'bill_no' => $this->input->post('bill_no'),
                'receive_type' => $this->input->post('receive_type'),
                'billed_date' => $this->input->post('billed_date'),
                'order_no' => $this->input->post('order_no'),
                'order_date' => $this->input->post('order_date'),
                'grn_no' => $this->input->post('auto_grn_no'),
                'auto_grn_no' => $auto_grn,
                'purchased_date' => $this->input->post('purchased_date'),
                'user' => ucfirst($this->session->userdata('name')),
                'order_status' => 'purchase',
                'payment_status'=> 'Pending',
                'status' => '1',           
                'warranty_start' => $this->input->post('warranty_start'),
                'warranty_years' => $this->input->post('warranty_years')            
    
            );
            $id = $this->Item_model->addInventoryUpdateStock($stock);        
        }  

 

if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $id != 0) {
            $count = $this->input->post('i');
    
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
                $inventory = $this->input->post('inventory' . $x);
                $make = $this->input->post('make' . $x);
                $model = $this->input->post('model' . $x);
                $unit_price = $this->input->post('unit_price' . $x);
                $vat = $this->input->post('vat' . $x);
                $discount = $this->input->post('discount' . $x);
                $warranty_start = $this->input->post('warranty_start' . $x);
                $warranty_years = $this->input->post('warranty_years' . $x);
                $serial_no = $this->input->post('serial_no' . $x);
                $qty = count($this->input->post('serial_no' . $x));
                $details[$x]['status'] = 1;
                $counter = 0;
                $cat = $this->input->post('category'. $x);
                if($cat == 1 || $cat==2) {
                    $qty = count($this->input->post('serial_no' . $x));
                } else {
                    $qty = $this->input->post('qty' . $x);
                }
                for ($y = 0; $y < $qty; $y++) {
                    $details[$counter]['inventory_update_stock_id'] = $id;
                    $details[$counter]['inventory'] = $inventory;
                    $details[$counter]['make'] = $make;
                    $details[$counter]['model'] = $model;
                    $details[$counter]['serial_no'] = $serial_no[$counter];
                    $details[$counter]['unit_price'] = $unit_price;
                    $details[$counter]['qty'] = 1;
                    $details[$counter]['vat'] = $vat;
                    $details[$counter]['discount'] = $discount;
                    $details[$counter]['status'] = 1;
                    $details[$counter]['item_code'] = "CSS/".$id ."/".$y;
                    $counter++;
                }    
                $this->Item_model->addInventoryUpdateStockDetails($details);         
            }
    if ($id != 0) {
                echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>"); 
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Added & Updated ..!!');                            
                redirect('item/addInventoryPurchase');
                }
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
            $this->render('item/addInventoryPurchase', $meta, $this->data);
        }
    }
```

Then I used the following view to perform this task.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkXYA.png)

Code in the view also as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;

    function addRow() {
        i++;

        $('#row_data').append("<tr id='addr" +i+ "'><td><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='addRow()' id='add-post' class='external'><i style='color: #00C853 !important;' class='fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle'></i></a></td>" +
            "<td><select name='inventory" + i + "' id='inventory" + i + "' onchange='changeCategoryNew("+i+")' class='select2 form-control' required>" +
            "<option value=''></option>" +
            <?php
            if (!empty($products)) {
                foreach ($products as $row) {

                    ?>

                    "<option label='<?= $row->category ?>' value='<?= $row->inventory_item_id ?>'><?= $row->inventory_item_id ?> - <?=addslashes($row->inventory_item_name) ?></option>" +

                    <?php
                }
            }

            ?>
            "</select><input type='hidden' id='category_c"+i+"' name='category"+i+"'></td>" +
            "<td><input  name='make" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Make' class='form-control input-md'></td>" +
            "<td><input  name='model" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Model' class='form-control input-md'></td>" +
            "<td  id='headerQty'><select name='serial_no"+i+"[]' id='serial_no"+i+"' class='serial_no form-control select2' multiple='multiple' style='width: 100%'></select><input type='hidden' name='qty"+i+"' id='qty"+i+"' placeholder='Quantity' class='form-control' style='width: 100%'/></td>" +
            "<td><input  name='unit_price" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Unit Price' class='form-control input-md'></td>" +
            "<td><input  name='vat" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='VAT' class='form-control input-md'></td>" +
            "<td><input  name='discount" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='DISCOUNT' class='form-control input-md'></td>" +
            "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='external remove'><i style='color: #dd4b39 !important;' class='fa fa-2x fa-minus-circle' id='addIcon'></i></a></td></tr>");
        // $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        $('#i').val(i);
        $('#inventory'+ i).select2();
        $("#serial_no"+i).select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
        });



    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
            var count = $('#tab_logic>tbody').children().length;
            if (count > 0) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });


        function chnageCategory(category) {
           if(category == 1 || category == 2) {
            $('#serial_no').next(".select2-container").show();
            $("#qty").hide();
            $('table tr th:contains("Quantity")').text('Serial No');
            $('table td').eq(4).css("width", "50%")
        } else {
            $('#serial_no').next(".select2-container").hide();
            $('table tr th:contains("Serial No")').text('Quantity');
                //$('#serial_no').replaceWith('<input type="number" step="any" name="unit_price0" placeholder="Price" class="form-control"/>');
            $('#serial_no').val(null).trigger('change');
            $("#qty").prop('type', 'number');
            $("#qty").show();
            $('table td').eq(4).css("width", "10%")
        }


    }


    $(document).on("click", ".select2-search__field", function () {
        $(".serial_no").select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
        });
    });
});

    function changeCategoryNew(id) {

        let category = $('#inventory'+id+' option:selected').attr('label');
        $('#category_c'+id).val(category);

        if(category == 1 || category == 2) {
            $('#serial_no'+id).next(".select2-container").show();
            $("#qty"+id).hide();
            $('table td').eq(4).css("width", "50%")
        } else {
            $('#serial_no'+id).next(".select2-container").hide();
            $('#serial_no'+id).val(null).trigger('change');
            $("#qty"+id).prop('type', 'number');
            $("#qty"+id).show();
            $('table td').eq(4).css("width", "10%")
        }

        console.log(category);

    }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var oTable = $('#ExData').dataTable({

            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "ALL"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            'bProcessing': true, 'bServerSide': true,
            'sAjaxSource': '<?= base_url() . "item/getInventoryPurchase" ?>',
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({
                    "name": "type",
                    "value": "1 "
                });
                $.ajax({'dataType': 'json', 'type': 'POST', 'url': sSource, 'data': aoData, 'success': fnCallback});
            },
            'fnRowCallback': function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {

            },
            "aoColumns": [{'sName':'ro_no'}, {'sName':'purchased_date'}, 
                {'sName':'bill_no'}, 
                {'sName':'billed_date'}, {'sName':'store_inventory_update_stock.order_no'}, 
                {'sName':'order_date'}, {'sName':'supplier_name'}, {'sName':'grn_no'}, {'sName':'receive_type'},  null],
            "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {

            }

        });
    });
</script>
<div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box box-info collapsed-box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Inventory Stock Update</h3>

            <div class="box-tools pull-right">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" style="font-size: 16px;" data-widget="collapse"><i
                    class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>

            </div>
            <!-- /.box-tools -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body" style="display: block">
            <form action="<?= site_url('item/addInventoryPurchase') ?>" method="post">
                <div class="row">

                   <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>GRN No</label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                        <input type="text" name="auto_grn_no" id="auto_grn_no" class="form-control"
                        value="<?= $auto_grn_no ?>" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Bill No</label>
                        <input type="text" name="bill_no" id="bill_no" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Billed Date </label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                        <input type="date" name="billed_date" id="billed_date" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Purchased Date </label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                        <input type="date" name="purchased_date" id="purchased_date" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Receive Type</label><font
                        style="font-size: 14px; color: #AA0000">*</font>
                        <select class="form-control" required name="receive_type">
                            <option value="">Select Receive Type</option>
                            <option value="Purchasing">Purchasing</option>
                            <option value="Donating">Donating</option>
                            <option value="Transfering">Transfering</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">                

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Supplier</label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                        <select name="supplier" id="supplier" class="form-control select2" required>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($supplier)) {
                                foreach ($supplier as $row) {

                                    ?>

                                    <option value="<?= $row->supplier_id ?>"><?= $row->supplier_name ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Receive Order No</label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                        <input type="text" name="ro_no" id="ro_no" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Warranty Start</label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                        <input type="date" name='warranty_start' placeholder='Warranty Start'
                        class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Warranty Years</label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                        <input type="text" name='warranty_years' placeholder='Warrenty Years'
                        class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!--<div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group"><label>Location</label><font style="color: #AA0000;font-size: 16px">*</font>
                            <select name="location_name" id="location_name" class="form-control select2" required>
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <?php
                                if (!empty($location)) {
                                    foreach ($location as $row) {

                                        ?>

                                        <option value="<?= $row->location_id ?>"><?= $row->location_name ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }

                                ?>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>-->

                </div>  
                <!--table-->

                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">

                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Inventory Item
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Make
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Model
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Serial No / Qty
                                </th>                            
                                <th class="text-center">
                                   Unit Price (Rs)
                               </th>
                               <th class="text-center">
                                VAT (Rs)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                DISCOUNT (Rs)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">


                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="row_data">
                        <tr id='addr0'>
                            <td>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addRow()" id="add-post" class="external"><i style="color: #00C853 !important;"
                                  class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                              </td>
                              <td style="width: 15%">
                                <input type="hidden" name="i" id="i" value="0">
                                <select name="inventory0" id="inventory0" onchange="changeCategoryNew(0)" class="form-control select2 inventorySelect" placeholder='Inventory Item' required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php
                                    if (!empty($products)) {
                                        foreach ($products as $row) {
                                            echo "<option label='".$row->category."' value='".$row->inventory_item_id."'>$row->inventory_item_id - $row->inventory_item_name</option>";
                                            ?>


                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }

                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <input type="hidden" id="category_c0" name="category0">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" step="any" name='make0' placeholder='Make' class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" step="any" name='model0' id="model" placeholder='Model' class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                            <td  id="headerQty">
                                <select name="serial_no0[]" id="serial_no0" class="serial_no form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%"></select>
                                <input type="hidden" name="qty0" id="qty0" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" style="width: 100%"/>
                            </td>

                            <td style="width: 8%">
                                <input type="text" name='unit_price0' placeholder='Unit Price'
                                class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 8%">
                                <input type="text" name='vat0' placeholder='VAT'
                                class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 5%">
                                <input type="text" name='discount0' placeholder='DISCOUNT'
                                class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='external '><i style='color: #dd4b39 !important;'
                               class='fa fa-2x fa-minus-circle' id='addIcon'></i></a>
                           </td>
                       </tr>

                   </tbody>
               </table>              
           </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <a style="float: right;margin-left: 20px;" href="<?= site_url('item/printBarcodes') ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Print Barcodes</a>
                <a style="float: right;" href="<?= site_url('item/updateBarcode') ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Update Items Codes with Locations</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Update Inventory Stock" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!--end of table-->
</div>

</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="ExData" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
        class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped reports-table">
        <thead id="th">
            <tr class="" style="background-color: #00e673 !important;">

                <th>Receive Order No</th>
                <th>Purchased Date</th> 
                <th>Bill No</th>
                <th>Billed Date</th>
                <th>Order No</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Supplier</th>
                <th>GRN No</th>
                <th>Receive Type</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">Loading Data from Server</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then the models are created as follows :

```
function addInventoryUpdateStock($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('store_inventory_update_stock', $data);
    $last = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $last;
}
function addInventoryUpdateStockDetails($data)
{
  $this->db->insert_batch('store_inventory_update_stock_details', $data);
  if ($this->db->affected_rows() == true) {
    foreach ($data as $array) {
               // dd($array);
        $this->db->select('qty');
        $q = $this->db->get_where('store_inventory_stock', array('inventory_item_id' => $array['inventory']));
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {

            $this->db->update('store_inventory_stock',
                array('qty' => ((int)$array['qty'] + (int)$q->row()->qty)),
                array('inventory_item_id' => $array['inventory']));


        } else {

            $this->db->insert('store_inventory_stock', array('inventory_item_id' => $array['inventory'], 'qty' => $array['qty']));

        }


    }
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

### Expected Result

Should be inserted multiple items at a time with qunatities or serial numbers.

### Actual Result

The code inserted items without any error when inserting single item with number of qunatities or number of serial numbers. But if I selected multiple items at a time using the above view, it will be inserted many number of duplicated rows to the tables than expected rows.

I was unable to capture the bug in my code. Can anyone help this for me ?

Comment: You shared the expected results, but what are the actual results? What is the error log/trace?

Comment: @
hassan. Pls. see on edit

Comment: please read [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.

Comment: @ 
Rick James. can't view the generated SQL. The view directly inserted values to the table. The issue is here that the duplicated records are inserted with the required records.